# Apply function to all columns in matrix using column means

Tags: r, apply, lapply, sapply

I have a matrix m (conisting of three columns, each consisting of integers and having a mean of 5,10, and 15 respectively):

`m <- round(matrix(data=cbind(rnorm(30, 5), rnorm(30, 10), rnorm(30, 15)), nrow=30, ncol=3), 0)`

Now, I would like to have a matrix of the same dimensions as m, where each value x is calculated as x minus the mean of the column in which x is found. How can this be done? I have tried applying various apply-functions (specifically, I have been looking at two questions by [user3640617](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43643665/r-apply-function-to-matrix-with-elements-of-vector-as-argument?rq=1) and [User60](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49618150/how-to-recode-multiple-columns-in-r)), but the problem seems to be that I can't use the mean of a row as an argument in `sapply`, `lapply` or `vapply`...

Example: If the `head(m)` is

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    6   11   14
[2,]    6    8   16
[3,]    6   11   15
[4,]    6   10   17
[5,]    5    9   15
[6,]    3   10   15
```

I want to get

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1   -1
[2,]    1   -2    1
[3,]    1    1    0
[4,]    1    0    2
[5,]    0   -1    0
[6,]   -2    0    0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use `apply(m, 2, function(x)(x-mean(x)))`

Another way is to use `t(t(m)-colMeans(m))`

Comment: Just for the beginners (like me): the copy-paste-variante would be
`apply(m, 2, function(x)(x-mean(x)))`

Comment: Note that the vectorized solution using `colMeans` is ~ 200 times faster than `apply` in a benchmark with a 200x50 matrix. Always try to use vectorized operations with R!

Comment: Yes, so I add a vectorized solution. I post the 'apply' because he asked for an "apply" solution. BTW, any suggestion for changing the broadcast direction when using vectorized operations? (I hate to transpose the matrix twice)

Comment: @VicaYang I did not want to criticise your answer, I just wanted to point out to Lukas that the vectorized solution is much faster :)

Answer (score 4):

you are looking for

```
scale(m,center=T,scale=F)[,]
```

another way is

```
sweep(m,2,colMeans(m))
```

but not as fast as the `scale`